# WordPress Gutenberg Popover, how to position at the cursor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've got a [`Popover`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/popover/) component that I'd like to position at the cursor. So for example, in a [`RichText`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/richtext/) component if the user's cursor is in the start/middle/end of a sentence, the Popover would appear **based on where the cursor is** currently at.

Quick Photoshop of how I'd like it to appear:

[image]

Basically how the Toolbar link Popover works.

---

I've spent all day on this & this is the closest I've come. Works in the editor, but doesn't work when in the full site editor. I'm using the now deprecated `getAnchorRect` property & would love to find a way to use the latest `anchor` prop.

```
import {
    registerFormatType,
    toggleFormat
} from '@wordpress/rich-text';
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { BlockControls, RichTextShortcut } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Popover, ToolbarButton, ToolbarGroup } from '@wordpress/components';
import { displayShortcut } from '@wordpress/keycodes';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

const InsertMyPopup = {
    name: 'insertmypopup',
    title: __('My Popup'),
    character: 'o',
    value: '',
};

const { name, title, character } = InsertMyPopup;
const type = `my-popup/${name}`;
let anchorRange;
let anchorRect;

registerFormatType(type, {
    title,
    tagName: name,
    className: null,
    active: false,

    edit({ isActive, value, onChange, contentRef }) {
        const onToggle = () => {
            // Set up the anchorRange when the Popover is opened.
            const selection = document.defaultView.getSelection();

            anchorRange =
                selection.rangeCount > 0 ? selection.getRangeAt(0) : null;

            // Pin the Popover to the caret position.
            const boundingClientRect = anchorRange
                ? anchorRange.getBoundingClientRect()
                : null;

            anchorRect = anchorRange ? () => boundingClientRect : null;
            onChange(toggleFormat(value, { type }));
        };

        const thePopover = isActive && (
            <Popover
                placement='bottom-start'
                focusOnMount='firstElement'
                key='my-popover'
                expandOnMobile={true}
                headerTitle={__(
                    'My Popup',
                    'insert-my-popup'
                )}
                onClose={() => {
                    onChange(toggleFormat(value, { type }));
                }}
                getAnchorRect={anchorRect}
            >
                Popup
            </Popover>
        );

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockControls group='other'>
                    <ToolbarGroup>
                        <ToolbarButton
                            icon='editor-customchar'
                            isPressed={isActive}
                            label={title}
                            onClick={onToggle}
                            shortcut={displayShortcut.primary(character)}
                        />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                </BlockControls>
                <Fragment>
                    <RichTextShortcut
                        type='primary'
                        character={character}
                        onUse={onToggle}
                        contentRef={contentRef}
                    />
                </Fragment>
                {thePopover}
            </Fragment>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: did you end up finding solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working by just adding the `contentRef.current` to the `anchor` property of the `Popover`.

```
edit({ isActive, value, onChange, contentRef }) {

    const [ popoverAnchor, setPopoverAnchor ] = useState(contentRef.current);

    // And then later on:

    <Popover anchor={ popoverAnchor }>

}
```